# Returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: api, google-api, blogger

I have a script that uses the Blogger API, it's been working great for over a year but today it is receiving an error when trying to update a blog post.

I'm not going to bother posting the code here as I'm positive it works (I was just using it yesterday and so were random people all over the world. But the error returned by the API is:

```
{ 
  "error": 
         { 
           "errors": [ 
                        { 
                          "domain": "global", 
                          "reason": "forbidden", 
                          "message": "Forbidden" 
                        } 
                     ], 
            "code": 403, 
            "message": "Forbidden" 
         }
}
```

Any ideas? Is it something with the particular blog I'm trying to edit? Do I need to reset my authorization? Just a blogger issue?

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar problem as yours (with the exact same error message). However, not sure if this will solve your problem.

What I found is when I turn off the rss feed of the blog, then request starts to get 403. If I turn it back on, suddenly it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had same experience for my first project with gecko profile...
.
Then I do it again for my second project but I delete gecko profile first and re login my gecko browser with new email and new app.  may be it can solve your problem